# How to show a file list ordered by taxonomy field with views?

Tags: views

I've a file type of type "document" with an additional field of type "term reference". When I upload a new file I can link a term of that vocabulary to my file, like it was a folder.

Now I need to list all my files in a tree manner like this:

`TERM_PARENT 1
  Term child 1
    - file.pdf
    - file.doc
    - file.ppt
  Term child 2
    - file.doc
    - file.pdf
TERM PARENT 2
  Term child 1
    - file.doc
TERM PARENT 3
  Term child 3
    - file.pdf
    - file.pdf`

How can I create a view like this?

Thanks a lot